# Guest optimization tips for Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, optimization

I was wondering if anyone could shed light into "Guest optimization tips for Ubuntu (guest)"

I came across [Virtual Machine guest optimization tips](https://serverfault.com/questions/18290/virtual-machine-guest-optimization-tips), for Windows.
(serverfault.com/questions/4647/ubuntu-inside-virtualbox-is-slow) is close enough, but not quite like the earlier question.

One thing I overlooked was installing additional drivers for guest. The VM felt much 'refined' after installing the addons.
I am obsessed by the thought that the guest and the host are going to fight out a memory battle. I plan to use eclipse/netbeans on Ubuntu with frequent switching to Vista.

Anyone with their experiences? Any Guest optimization tips for Ubuntu as a guest?

PS: the second hyperlink is not linked due to the curse of "a new user".

Comment: What operating system do you have the Virtual Box hypervisor installed in?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu's got a kernel meant explicitly for running in virtual machines; you might want to take a look at that. The package is called `linux-virtual`.

Answer (score 3):

A very basic, but in my opinion often forgot, tip is to simple uninstall all the programs not needed - even the X graphical user interface (if you don't depend on it).

Like already mentioned: using the VM optimized kernel will normally give you a huge performance boost and is most of the times recommended.

If you need your VM for some special tasks only, try thinking about a window manager switch. Moving from Gnome to a more lightweight and ressource-friendly WM like XFCE, Fluxbox, etc. can lower the memory usage, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Ubuntu, try JEOS.
A few tips in my earlier post here.

[Which Linux distribution runs smoothly in Sun's VirtualBox?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40086/which-linux-distribution-runs-smoothly-in-suns-virtualbox)

Most tips for a linux audio workstation and linux on older hardware are applicable to virtuals.